# Can not keep id serially of textbox using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue.I am adding multiple textbox using `+` button and deleting using `-` button. Here i am unable to keep each textbox's id serially. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="form-group" id="intro-box">
    <input type="text" style="width:85%;float:left;margin-bottom:5px;" class="form-control" id="introlabelname0" name="introlabelname" placeholder="Label Name" value="">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="addMore(1);">
  </div>
  <script>
    var a = 0;
    function addMore(i) {

        a = a + 1;

        i = a;

        $("#plus").remove();

        $('#intro-box').append('<div><input type="text" style="width:85%;float:left; margin-bottom:5px;" class="form-control" id="introlabelname' + i + '" name="introlabelname" placeholder="Label Name" value="">' +
        '<input type="button" onclick="removeThis(' + i + ');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus' + i + '" value="-" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;"></div>' +
        '<div> <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="addMore(' + (i++) + ');"></div>');
    }

    function removeThis(j) {
        $("#introlabelname" + j).remove();
        $("#minus" + j).remove();
    }
</script>
```

Here my problem is the id is increasing like `introlabelname0,introlabelname1,introlabelname2..`  this but while suppose deleting `introlabelname1` textbox and adding again its coming `introlabelname0,introlabelname2,introlabelname3` like this. Here i need suppose `introlabelname1` deleting from `introlabelname0,introlabelname1,introlabelname2..` it should `introlabelname0,introlabelname1` and if adding again it should `introlabelname0,introlabelname1,introlabelname2`. Always all textbox id will remain serially from `0,1,2...` and so on. Here is [my full code](https://plnkr.co/edit/2sBTN5WG3lWVeyM6mIKW?p=preview). Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to loop over all the input box, and create the new ID(s) with index value. First of all give the text box class name :

```
class="form-control inputBox"
```

Then add this function :

```
function repopulate() {
  $( '.inputBox' ).each( function ( i, e) {
      $( this ).attr( 'id','introlabelname' + i );
      $( this ).next().attr( 'onClick', function (old,n) {
        return 'removeThis(' + i + ')';
      });
      $( this ).next().attr( 'id', function (old,n) {
        return 'minus' + i;
      });
  })  
}
```

Last, for each function calling, call this function :

```
repopulate();
```

Here is updated [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/wqu0skky/)

*p/s : you should edit the HTML,it not properly structured*

Comment: Anyway you can use this https://github.com/metallurgical/jquery-metal-clone for cloning DOM element

Comment: Here is one problem in your plunkr.create two text field and delete 2nd one. all are deleting.

Comment: I create the another one inside jsfiddle, Check it out. Actually your HTML is messed up

Answer (score 2):

```
You can also do like this.
```

1.I added var i = $(".inputBox").length + 1; this line in addMore function it calculate the current input box count and add serialize number to new input box.

2.Also I include serialize() function it makes serialize your input box and button ids.

```
function addMore(i) {
        var i = $(".inputBox").length + 1;
        $("#plus").remove();
        $('#intro-box').append('<div><input type="text" style="width:85%;float:left; margin-bottom:5px;" class="form-control inputBox" id="introlabelname' + i + '" name="introlabelname" placeholder="Label Name" value="">' +
        '<input type="button" onclick="removeThis(' + i + ');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus' + i + '" value="-" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;"></div>' +
        '<div> <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="addMore(' + (i++) + ');"></div>');
    }

    function removeThis(j) {
        $("#introlabelname" + j).remove();
        $("#minus" + j).remove();
        serialize();
    }

    function serialize(){
      var i=1;
      $(".inputBox").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("id", "introlabelname"+i);
        $(this).next().attr("id", "minus"+i);
        i++;
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to decrement the a variable when you remove a row:

```
function removeThis(j) {
    $("#introlabelname" + j).remove();
    $("#minus" + j).remove();
    a = a - 1;
}
```

Comment: NO,its not coming as per required. I have updated the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uuvvf7AzTxY3jqTf1ywg?p=preview).

Comment: @ Craig : I created 4 text field and deleted 2nd one (`i.e-introlabelname1`). Finally its coming  `introlabelname0.introlabelname1,introlabelname3` where it should `introlabelname0.introlabelname1,introlabelname2`.